# Azure Import Database - Missing the required 'administratorLogin' parameters for ImportExport operation

Tags: azure, import, azure-sql-database

Thru Azure portal, we are trying to import bacpac file into Azure SQL server.

It was working fine before and now when we are selecting backpac file from storage account, we are getting below error.

---

At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. (Code: DeploymentFailed)

**Error details**

Missing the required 'administratorLogin' parameters for ImportExport operation. (Code: BadRequest)

---

I tried with old bacpac file which was imported successfully in Azure SQL server.

I tried same file thru Azure functions & Import API and it is working fine and as expected, only thru portal we are facing this issue.

Is this issue in Azure portal itself?

Comment: check this post if you have not already https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/05/09/export-azure-sql-db-error-missing-the-required-administratorlogin-parameters-for-importexport-operation/

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I looked at this before, so then i tried with IE 11, but same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created support ticket and support engineer suggested me to try with incognito window.

During this activity, I saw that default value of "Authentication Type" was "Active Directory" instead of "SQL Server". This happened after 9-Aug, so it seems that this may be changed in new build for Azure Portal before 9-Aug, I did't noticed it and was providing SQL credentials for Active Directory type. So now when changed "Authentication Type" to SQL server & passed SQL credentials, it worked.

Thanks Alberto for your help.

So the Issue was related to selecting Authentication Type as "Active Directory" instead of "SQL server"

I think error message should be related to cause of it.

Answer (score 1):

I will report the issue but as a workaround you can use SqlPackage or PowerShell to import the database.

Using PowerShell:

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport –ResourceGroupName “sqlgroup” –ServerName “powershellserver” –DatabaseName “mypowershelldatabase” –StorageKeytype “StorageAccessKey” –StorageKey $primarykey -StorageUri $StorageUri –AdministratorLogin $credential.UserName –AdministratorLoginPassword $credential.Password –Edition Basic –ServiceObjectiveName B -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes 50000
```

Using SqlPackage:

```
SqlPackage /Action:Import /TargetServerName:SampleSQLServer.sample.net,1433 /TargetUser:CloudSA /TargetPassword:secret /SourceFile:"F:\Temp\SampleDatabase.bacpac"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. OK. I was able to import thru Import API.

Comment: @ManishJoisar Please share with me on what region you were trying to import the database.

Comment: Location is West US 2

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: I contacted the Azure SQL Database about the BadRequest error and for them it is not a known issue. To further investigate the cause of the error they would like you to open a support ticket. Thank you for your patience,

Comment: OK, Thanks for your help

Comment: I have not received an update about this error. It was a totally new and unknown error. They wanted you to create a support ticket because providing a subscription id online is not recommended since it is sensitive information.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, will do and then will update as and when i have any

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue today. For me the fix was to remove the active directory admin user from the server. The databases are all SQL Server security, but the server was requiring an AD login. Took a bit of noodling but it works.